# Simple Jquery Fold Down

Tags: jquery, slide

I am new to Jquery and need some help: I have a div, I want to click on it and roll down another div, but I want to click on it again and have it fold up, I know its easy but im stumped. Heres the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

});

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, use [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SsBwj/)**.

jQuery:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
    $('#book').slideToggle();
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">click me</div>
<div id="book">book</div>​
```